# Rendering markdown text in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown

I want to convert markdown to html. In my views I have `markdown(some_text_variable)` but I get the error `undefined method markdown`.

I added `require 'BlueCoth'` to enviroment.rb and I installed the BlueCloth gem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 49):

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bluecloth'
```

and don't forget to run

```
bundle install
```

when you need to convert markdown to html, simply use:

```
markdown = BlueCloth.new(some_text_variable).to_html
```

You can use it in a view:

```rb
<%= markdown.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Things to save others some time: This is the latest version of the gem: https://github.com/ged/bluecloth and I had to add .html_safe after .to_html for thing to render properly in a rails 3.2 .erb template

Comment: @BaronVonKaneHoffen bluecloth is awesome! Thanks for your excellent works!

Comment: I would add a `raw` in front of that in my view to get HTML rendered and not visible `<p>` tags etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RDiscount
https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend against bluecloth as it doesn't look like it's being upkept that well.

Best thing I've found out there as of now (summer 2013) is the Redcarpet gem: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet

Answer (score 2):

The `#markdown` helper was [removed in Rails 3](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0919c0dbca3df02f5cfff7dde4f61b85ef16d886).

You can copy & paste the code from the commit or use a third party Gem, like [formatize](https://github.com/dtrasbo/formatize). You will also have to include the required `BlueCloth`/`RedCloth`/etc gem in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Worked for me without explicitly including `BlueCloth` in my Gemfile. I added `formatize` to my Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, and restarted webrick and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `environment.rb` instead of the require:

```
config.gem 'BlueCloth', :lib => 'bluecloth'
```

In Rails 3, this would be in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'bluecloth'
```

The gem is called BlueCloth, but the .rb file that gets required is all lowercase.

Make sure you restart rails after adding the config.gem line.