# Making a basic SO-like WYSIWYG editor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown, wmd-editor

I am relatively new to Rails, having recently completed Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and am now embarking on my first full fledged project.  What I am interested in adding to my web app is something similar to the text input feature in SO, where you could type, and see directly how your text will turn out.   After [some](http://epochwolf.com/blog/2010/01/18/using-bluecloth-20/) [digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578825/rendering-markdown-text-in-rails-3) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602040/bluecloth-isnt-working-with-rails-3) on SO, I have decided on using the gem `bluecloth`, which is Markdown implemented in Ruby, but now have the following questions:

1. I am unsure about how to tie what `bluecloth` outputs to the `form_for` helper.  My understanding  was that you could convert to strings via the function `html = BlueCloth.new(str).to_html()`, but I am unsure what to do when you have a text field as part of `form_for`, where I should plug in the bluecloth part?  In other words, I am still a bit confused about the magic of typing in one box and seeing the item show elsewhere on the page.
2. Are the WMD bar button items and functions included Markdown editors (such as bluecloth), or would this be something I have to build manually?  If so, how would I get something like the **bold** button to show "** **" in the editor as you type?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: whats wrong with a premade solution such as tinymce-rails ?

Comment: Nothing wrong at all :) I just started researching these editors, so haven't happened upon tinyMCE yet.  I just looked at it though, and there seem to be an overwhelming amount of editing options.  Would I be able to selectively install and configure it to just be a select few?

Comment: from my understanding, BlueCloth converts text to html. Meanwhile tinyMCE is a complete WYSIWYG solution with better documentation.

Comment: Markdown != WYSIWYG, you'll be writing a lot of code and browser hacks to get it to work like one. Like Andrew is saying TinyMCE is kind of the de facto solution. http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/ is also an amazing project. Somewhat robust, a rails project called Mercury also exists that might be easy to jump into after watching Ryan Bate's video http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  Wysihtml5 looks great and I'll certainly look more into it.  Also didn't know Markdown != WYSIWYG.. this was a good clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comments have noted, Markdown is a markup language like HTML, so its not easy to do WYSIWYG.

There are probably two approaches to getting this kind of functionality.

**Server side**

Post your markdown text to a server and get the server to return HTML.  I've done this a lot in Python, but for Ruby [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373002/better-ruby-markdown-interpreter) suggests [maruku](http://maruku.rubyforge.org/).  The disadvantage of this approach is that it requires a server request every time you want to view the preview, and then some way to integrate that back into your UI without disrupting the user. Stackoverflow uses this approach with the [WMD editor and some C# on the server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121981/stackoverflow-official-wmd-editor).

**Client side**

Another option is to use a client side library to take your markdown "code" and generate html which you can then integrate into your page using javascript.  An example of this is [dillinger](http://dillinger.io/).  This uses a textarea and something like [showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) to render the HTML in the browser.  I'm taking this approach one step further in a WYSIWYG Markdown editor I'm developing called [demarcate.js](https://github.com/will-hart/demarcate.js)

**Or... ditch Markdown**

The comments have already suggested alternative WYSIWYG editors... most of these are not markdown editors but *rich text editors* which produce HTML at the end. [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/) are good options and I've also used [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) before with some success - it has a cool "in-place" feature in the latest version which inspired my Markdown editor above.

Comment: Thank you for your well crafted answer and suggestions. The client side/server side breakdown was especially helpful.  At the moment I looked into wysihtml5 and decided it would be the best fit for me.  Thanks again!