# render md file as partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I am using the markdown rails gem 
https://github.com/joliss/markdown-rails
I have an md partial _privacy.html.md

```
#Privacy Policy
Privacy policy ....
```

Then when I render this partial file from an erb file

```
<%= render :partial => "privacy" %>
```

I get

`<h1>Privacy Policy</h1> <p> Privacy policy ....`

It actually renders the formatted html as a text and not as as an html interpreted code.

Comment: Have you searched for an `html_safe` method, like another gem does? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108644/8122487

Answer (score -1):

> render md file as partial in rails

Try this one

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

puts Nokogiri::HTML(my_html).text
```

**Example:**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

uri = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279017/render-md-file-as-partial-in-rails'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))
doc.css('script, link').each { |node| node.remove }
puts doc.css('body').text.squeeze(" \n")
```

or **simple way**:

```
html = '<div class="asd">hello world</div><p><span>Happy</span><br> to help</p>'
puts ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(html)
```

and

```
html.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, ' ').gsub(/\n\n+/, '\n').gsub(/^\n|\n$/, ' ').squish
```

Hope this will help you !